# in high charts gauge how to set the numbers in meter reading

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

i want to show high charts meter gauge where i need to show the reading -20 to 0 (-20,19,18,17,16....0) not like (-20,-10,0)

see fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-vu-meter/

code

```
  Highcharts.chart('container', {

        chart: {
            type: 'gauge',
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            plotBackgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#FFF4C6'],
                    [0.3, '#FFFFFF'],
                    [1, '#FFF4C6']
                ]
            },
            plotBackgroundImage: null,
            height: 200
        },

        title: {
            text: 'VU meter'
        },

        pane: [{
            startAngle: -50,
            endAngle: 50,
            background: null,
            center: ['25%', '145%'],
            size: 300
        }, {
            startAngle: -45,
            endAngle: 45,
            background: null,
            center: ['75%', '145%'],
            size: 300
        }],

        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },

        yAxis: [{
            min: -20,
            max: 6,
            minorTickPosition: 'outside',
            tickPosition: 'outside',
            labels: {
                rotation: 'auto',
                distance: 20
            },
            plotBands: [{
                from: 0,
                to: 6,
                color: '#C02316',
                innerRadius: '100%',
                outerRadius: '105%'
            }],
            pane: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'VU<br/><span style="font-size:8px">Channel A</span>',
                y: -40
            }
        }, {
            min: -20,
            max: 6,
            minorTickPosition: 'outside',
            tickPosition: 'outside',
            labels: {
                rotation: 'auto',
                distance: 20
            },
            plotBands: [{
                from: 0,
                to: 6,
                color: '#C02316',
                innerRadius: '100%',
                outerRadius: '105%'
            }],
            pane: 1,
            title: {
                text: 'VU<br/><span style="font-size:8px">Channel B</span>',
                y: -40
            }
        }],

        plotOptions: {
            gauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                dial: {
                    radius: '100%'
                }
            }
        },


        series: [{
            name: 'Channel A',
            data: [-20],
            yAxis: 0
        }, {
            name: 'Channel B',
            data: [-20],
            yAxis: 1
        }]

    }
     );
```

Comment: There is literally no question asked in your "Question".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yse0xu8e/)

I simply changed the `max` and `min` fields in y-axis and changed the javascript function to accommodate the new intervals.

**EDIT:** I didn't understand the question before, but according to your comment this should work. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/872yLzLs/)

**EDIT2:** Only now I saw you edited the question. Updated the link in EDIT to contain values from -20 to 0 (Before it was from 0 to 20).

Comment: sorry that was not my requirement, i want the meter reading should be 1 to 20 without any gap like 1.2.3.4.5.6.....20.now im getting 1, 10 and 20 only

Answer (score 0):

Change chart.yAxis.min and chart.yAxis.max:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        plotBackgroundColor: {
            linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
            stops: [
                [0, '#FFF4C6'],
                [0.3, '#FFFFFF'],
                [1, '#FFF4C6']
            ]
        },
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        height: 200
    },

    title: {
        text: 'VU meter'
    },

    pane: [{
        startAngle: -45,
        endAngle: 45,
        background: null,
        center: ['25%', '145%'],
        size: 300
    }, {
        startAngle: -45,
        endAngle: 45,
        background: null,
        center: ['75%', '145%'],
        size: 300
    }],

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },

    yAxis: [{
        min: 0,
        max: 20,
        minorTickPosition: 'outside',
        tickPosition: 'outside',
        labels: {
            rotation: 'auto',
            distance: 20
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: 15,
            to: 20,
            color: '#C02316',
            innerRadius: '100%',
            outerRadius: '105%'
        }],
        pane: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'VU<br/><span style="font-size:8px">Channel A</span>',
            y: -40
        }
    }, {
        min: -20,
        max: 10,
        minorTickPosition: 'outside',
        tickPosition: 'outside',
        labels: {
            rotation: 'auto',
            distance: 20
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 10,
            color: '#C02316',
            innerRadius: '100%',
            outerRadius: '105%'
        }],
        pane: 1,
        title: {
            text: 'VU<br/><span style="font-size:8px">Channel B</span>',
            y: -40
        }
    }],

    plotOptions: {
        gauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            dial: {
                radius: '100%'
            }
        }
    },


    series: [{
        name: 'Channel A',
        data: [10],
        yAxis: 0
    }, {
        name: 'Channel B',
        data: [-10],
        yAxis: 1
    }]

},

    // Let the music play
    function (chart) {
        setInterval(function () {
            if (chart.series) { // the chart may be destroyed
                var left = chart.series[0].points[0],
                    right = chart.series[1].points[0],
                    leftVal,
                    rightVal,
                    inc = Math.random() - 0.5;

                leftVal = left.y + inc;
                rightVal = leftVal + inc;

                left.update(leftVal, false);
                right.update(rightVal, false);
                chart.redraw();
            }
        }, 500);

    });
```

Comment: i was finding solution for showing meter reading without a gap (-20,-19,18..).here its showing reading with a gap of 10 , i need it gap should be only of 1